# vlookup using UNIX shell

Tags: linux, csv

I have this CSV file

```
ID,col1,col2,col3
1,,,FALSE
2,,,FALSE
3,,,FALSE
4,,,FALSE
```

and I want to join it using ID column with this other CSV file

```
ID,col1
2,AA
3,BB
```

to obtain (the real output must be another CSV, here there is a pretty print output, to be more readable)

```
+----+------+------+-------+
| ID | col1 | col2 | col3  |
+----+------+------+-------+
| 1  | -    | -    | FALSE |
| 2  | AA   | -    | FALSE |
| 3  | BB   | -    | FALSE |
| 4  | -    | -    | FALSE |
+----+------+------+-------+
```

And finally when `col1` is not empty, `col3` must be `TRUE`

```
+----+------+------+-------+
| ID | col1 | col2 | col3  |
+----+------+------+-------+
| 1  | -    | -    | FALSE |
| 2  | AA   | -    | TRUE  |
| 3  | BB   | -    | TRUE  |
| 4  | -    | -    | FALSE |
+----+------+------+-------+
```

How to do it, using some Linux command line utility or bash script?

Comment: Is both files are csv OR in excel ?If both are csv then  did you try join -t"," abc.csv xyz.csv ? If expected result like that you may further use awk for formatting.

Comment: Bash is not SQL, it is hard to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller). Running

```
mlr --csv join --ul -j ID -f input01.csv then put -S '!is_empty($col1) { $col3 = "TRUE" }' then sort -n ID input02.csv >output.csv
```

you will have

```
+----+------+------+-------+
| ID | col1 | col2 | col3  |
+----+------+------+-------+
| 1  | -    | -    | FALSE |
| 2  | AA   | -    | TRUE  |
| 3  | BB   | -    | TRUE  |
| 4  | -    | -    | FALSE |
+----+------+------+-------+
```

Some notes:

- `join` to run join using `ID` field;
- `put` to check if col1 is not empty;
- `sort` to sort records by ID

Comment: How to install miller ??

Comment: @user3016638 read the documentation http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/build.html#Prebuilt_executables

Comment: is this is freeware ?

Comment: @user3016638 free and opensource

Comment: how to install on windows and i don't see straight forward way to install

Comment: @user3016638 open please another new question in stack overflow "how to install miller in windows". This is unix stack exchange: do you not use unix/linux?